# cells shift when clearing

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm having an issue with some code that I've written for a worksheet that copies data from another sheet. Simply put, cells A8 through I1000 or so are filled with formulas and the like. Essentially these are filled with data from another sheet automatically through this code.

```
Sub CopyPasteC()

Dim ALastFundRow As Integer
Dim AFirstBlankRow As Integer
Dim wksSource As Worksheet, wksDest As Worksheet
Dim rngStart As Range, rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range

Set wksSource = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("dt")
Set wksDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Wr")

On Error Resume Next

'Finds last row of content
ALastFundRow = wksSource.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

 'Finds first row without content
AFirstBlankRow = CLastFundRow + 1

'Copy Data
Set rngSource = wksSource.Range("A2:A" & ALastFundRow)

'Paste Data Values
Set rngDest = wksDest.Range("C8:C" & ALastFundRow + 7)

rngSource.Copy

rngDest.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

'Bring back to top of sheet for consistancy
wksDest.Range("C8").Select

End Sub
```

However, when the dt sheet is blank, the wr sheet tries to pull all of this unsuccessfully since there is nothing there and is left with the old data.

Instead I'd like it to appear blank with the formulas intact. So I used this code:

```
Sub Deleteallbutformulas()

On Error Resume Next

Range("A8:M500").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents

End Sub
```

However, for whatever reason even though I'm using clearcontents, the cells in row 7, which are filled with label headers, shift down one cell to row 8 and switch places so that row 7 is now filled with the formulas that belong in row 8. I've checked for merged cells and all and can't find the issue that's making the cells move.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `AFirstBlankRow = CLastFundRow + 1`: AFirstBlankRow will always = 1. Need to change that to `AFirstBlankRow = ALastFundRow + 1`

Comment: Thanks but that's just a nuance in the spreadsheet. Column C will always contain the last row with a cell that contains data. I tried it anyways but nothing changed. Still having the issue with rows 7 and 8 swapping.

Comment: I can't find what is your question...

Comment: @DavidG. essentially when the last group of code is executed, rows 7 and 8 swap places even though I used the clearcontents function which should shift any of the cells.